# How to dynamically make a field visible?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to render a field based on a select value. However I couldn't succeed for now, so here is what I tried:

I created a content type with a select field (field_type)

```
var_dump($form['field_type']['und']['#options']);
```

gives

```
array (size=5)
  '_none' => string '- Select a value -' (length=18)
  'externe' => string 'externe' (length=7)
  'interne' => string 'interne' (length=7)
  'carroussel' => string 'carroussel' (length=10)
  'vitrine' => string 'vitrine' (length=7)
```

I noticed 'und' by printing my field and reading the first comment on this page 
[Drupal process states 7.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7.x)

and my field that should be visible (or not)

```
$form['field_target_text'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#states' => array(
          'visible' => array(
            'input[name="field_type[und]"' => array('value'=>'interne')
          ),
        ),
      );
```

I tried to replace input with select, to remove [und] but nothing did the job until I replaced the field like this

```
$form['field_type'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => ('TYPE TPE'),
        '#description' => ('TEST.'),
        '#options' => $form['field_type']['und']['#options']
      ];
```

Seems like he doesn't like my field not having an ['#options'] but ['und']['#options']. However by doing so, when I save my node, the field_type is empty.

Any help or advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `]` in the selector `':input[name="field_type[und]"'` code test with the following it will work.

```
':input[name="field_type[und]"]' => ['value' => 'interne'],
```

**Update:**
The state work with any valid JQuery selector, so if you looking to target it with `select` selector instead of `:input` you can use this:

```
 'select[name="field_type[und]"]' => ['value' => 'interne'],
```

Comment: He was also missing the `:` in front of `:input[]`. By the way, any advantage to using `:input[]` instead of `select[]` in this case? I personally find it easier to read/understand the code if the selector for a select element is an actual `select` tag. One disadvantage to using `:input` is that you don't know what kind of field the selector is for without looking somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Actually i didn't test without the : I have only test what I posted it works

Comment: I don't think `input[]`, (without the `:`), will work as a selector for  `#type => 'select'`. [`':input` is a jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) for selecting "all input, textarea, select and button elements"

Comment: event if it's a selector for input, you target it with `name="field_type[und]"` which is unique depends on field machine name!

Comment: Check my update, with select also works!

Comment: I hope you didn't misunderstand my comments. I wasn't saying that your answer was wrong. I was wondering why all Drupal documentation uses `:input[name="field_name"]` as the example, when any jQuery selector that uniquely identifies the field will work. You can use the `id` of the field: `'#edit-field-type-und'`, or add a unique class to the field and use it `'.my-unique-class'`. You can even use `name` with jQuery's [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector) to be language neutral: `':input[name^="field_type"]'` or `'select[name^="field_type"]'`

Comment: feels bad to miss an ']' x)